# Selenium - how to select element properly in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to select the following element in selenium

```
<div class="u8-contextmenu-item u8-contextmenu-parentitem-selection" id="n59" data-helptext="Companies" data-helpuri="help://dom" style="display:block;">
    <div class="u8-contextmenu-item-image" style="width: 16px;" data- size="s">
        <span class="img u8-img-infoarea-fi-s"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="u8-contextmenu-popup-image">
        <span class="img u8-img-arrow-r-xs"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="u8-contextmenu-item-text">Companies</div>
</div>
```

I can't use id for some internal reasons, so I need to access via the data-helptext element but I don't know how.

```
data-helptext="Companies"
```

Can you please give me some hints, how to resolve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ` I need to to on the data-helptext elment`? Do you want to retrieve the text from the attribute _data-helptext_ i.e. **Companies**?

Comment: Sorry for the unclearness. I need to go on the data helptext. I need to access the element where "data-helptext="Companies"" is true

Comment: I have several elements which would fullfill your xpath, but i just have one where datahelptext=Companies? :) How can I add this to your code? driver.findElements(By.xpath("//element[@attribute='data-helptext="Companies"']")) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get the webelement having attribute `data-helptext` :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-helptext='Companies']");
```

If you have multiple HTML elements with the same attribute and value. Use

```
List<WebElement> expectedElelemnts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-helptext='Companies']");
```

Now iterate over the list of web elements and check for the expected element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve an attribute by searching by the [element](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//element[@attribute='data-helptext']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the element where the attribute *data-helptext* contains the value **Companies** you can use the following line of code :

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='u8-contextmenu-item u8-contextmenu-parentitem-selection' and @data-helptext='Companies']"));
```

Comment: @user3898488 Check out my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

Non solution worked.. I dont know why.

What worked was:

```
$('*').removeAttr('id')
```

in chrome, and then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]")).click();
```

This is the only solution which I found and worked...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **cssSelector** :

```
div[class$='contextmenu-parentitem-selection']~div[class$='contextmenu-item-text']
```

Comment: try this cssSelector and let me know if it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you guys mentioned are defintely correct, anyway its NOT working in selenium.

The only things which are working:

1.) Selection by ID, if accidentally the ID in the code matches the ID of the during runtime generated ID

2.)  selection via 
    /html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]

In chrome development window, they all show to the same element, so im totally lost why its not working...